# gamecontrollerd taking up CPU, how to disable gamecontrollerd?

Tags: big-sur, activity-monitor

On my mac I see that gamecontrollerd is take 1+% CPU. I don't ever use a game controller and it doesn't seem useful for it to be running at all. Is there some setting to disable it? What is it doing?

macOS Big Sur (11.2.1)
MacBook Pro 15" 2016

Comment: What version of macOS are you running on which model of Macintosh?

Comment: @IconDaemon I've now added this information to the description. Does that help?

Comment: [This question and answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406595/how-do-i-remove-gamecontrollerd-axvisualsupportagent-and-viewbridgeauxilia#:~:text=Gamecontrollerd%20runs%20when%20certain%20programs,apple.com%2Fthread%2F252046047) here at AskDifferent my provide some clues and a possible solution.

Comment: no it does not, that question does not apply to big sur

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same, that `gamecontrollerd` takes up quite a lot of cpu. Sometimes 2% on a MacBookPro 2016. And I don't use a game controller.